# Construct a function like Coefficient

Tags: functions, function-construction, pattern-matching

I'am trying to construct a function that will work like `Coefficient` as an exercise.

```
meuCoefficient1 // ClearAll
meuCoefficient1[_?NumericQ, x_Symbol] := 0
meuCoefficient1[(a_: 1)*x_Symbol + (b_: 0), x_Symbol] := a
meuCoefficient1[(a_: 1)*y_Symbol + (b_: 0), x_Symbol] := 0
meuCoefficient1[y_Symbol, x_Symbol] := 0
meuCoefficient1[y_Symbol + n_?NumericQ, x_Symbol] := 0
```

For the most cases my new function (`meuCoefficient`) works very well, except for the case when I have `meuCoefficient[a*x + x,x]`. In this case the solution has to be `a+1`, but my function is not defined for this case.

How should I extend my definition?

Answer (score 1):

There are probably many ways to what you are asking. Here is one way, very likely not the best, but one which tries to maintain the style of your approach.

```
myCoeff // Clear
myCoeff[(a_.) y_Symbol, x_Symbol] /; y === x := a
myCoeff[poly_?PolynomialQ, x_Symbol] := Plus @@ Cases[poly, (a_.) x -> a]
myCoeff[_, x_Symbol] := 0
```

#### Tests

```
myCoeff[x, x]
```

> `1`

```
myCoeff[3 x + b, x]
```

> `3`

```
myCoeff[a x + b, x]
```

> `a`

```
myCoeff[3 x + x, x]
```

> `4`

```
myCoeff[a x + x, x]
```

> `1 + a`

```
myCoeff[a x + b x, x]
```

> `a + b`

```
myCoeff[a x + a x, x]
```

> `2 a`

Comment: This is a good solution! But there is a way to do that without using `Cases`? @m_goldberg

Comment: @Mateus. Very likely there is, but why do you object to `Cases`?

Comment: Because I want to use less then possible the functions of Mathematica

Comment: @Mateus. You mean you want to do all the work in the righthand side of the function definition? But even so, you will have use functions such as `Condition` ( `/;` ) and `PolynomialQ`. IMO, imposing such a constraint will be more trouble than it's worth.

Comment: I can use conditions (`/;`) and `PolynomialQ`. I just want to avoid functions like `Collect`, `Cases` etc...

Answer (score 1):

```
ClearAll[meuCoefficient2 ]
meuCoefficient2[a_, x_Symbol] := Replace[a, _?(FreeQ[x] ) :> 0, {0, 1}] /. x -> 1

meuCoefficient2[#, x] & /@ {a + 5 + y, 5 + x, a + a x + x,  5 + y + a x + b x^2}
```

> {0, 1, 1 + a, a + b}

Also

```
ClearAll[meuCoefficient3]
meuCoefficient3[a_, x_] /; FreeQ[a, x] := 0
meuCoefficient3[a_.  b_, x_] := a
meuCoefficient3[a_Plus, x_] := meuCoefficient3[#, x] & /@ a
meuCoefficient3[#, x] & /@ {a + 5 + y, 5 + x, a + a x + x, 5 + y + a x + b x^2}
```

> {0, 1, 1 + a, a + b}